# What's this kanji with circles?

Tags: kanji

[image]

I found out about this from what appears to be a Japanese calligrapher on YouTube. He says it's a historic version of 恋, but the only evidence of it being historical I found was from a blog with little to no information about it. Where can I find out more about this character?

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, it seems there’s some credit to the story. According to the Goo辞典, the old version of 恋 is 戀 and that one does [have the variant you are showing](http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u6200).

Here it is in the Ministry of Justice [family register character database](http://houmukyoku.moj.go.jp/KOSEKIMOJIDB/M01.html):

[image]

You can see that the “proper” character (正字) is 戀